# Не удается расширить jQuery prototype

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
Object.defineProperty(jQuery.prototype, 'fname', {
    value: function() {
        ...
    }
});
```

При попытке вызвать `jQuery('.class').fname()` ругается: `jQuery(...).fname is not a function`. В чем может быть проблема? На том же `jsfiddle` все работает: https://jsfiddle.net/wqfddjy8/

Та же функция на других сайтах с той же версией `jQuery` работает нормально. Может ли это быть из-за конфликтов скриптов? Если да, то какие существуют пути решения проблемы? Сайт большой и сделан не мной, пока просмотрю все скрипты на возможность конфликта - уйдет довольно много времени.

Comment: Возможно у вас подгружается несколько копий jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Подключен ваш скрипт после jQuery? Если сайт большой, тем более на движке, проверьте, не подключается ли jQuery несколько раз, в том числе, после вашего скрипта. 
Попробуйте:

```
window.onload=function(){
Object.defineProperty(jQuery.prototype, 'fname', {
  value: function() {
    this.text('Text2');
  }
});
jQuery('span').fname();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Проблема оказалась в конфликте имен - в одном из моих скриптов расширялся `prototype` типа `Object`, а в другом скрипте на сайте использовались методы с теми же именами.